# How do I change Text Editor theme?

Tags: fonts

[Styling Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z5cr.jpg)

So in sudo gedit to edit a file that is otherwise locked down, it has this really weird behavior of making your CSS syntax for assigning a value to a property be white font, and the active line is a white background. You'd think I'd just go to the preferences, font & colors, and double click a better option for a dark theme, right?

Oh, but if only. Double click, pressing enter, pressing space, nothing changes the selection.

If I launch the text editor application and go through the same menu and settings, that will let me change settings. But I can't do the same for the sudo gedit. That's crazy to me.

What do?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using sudo, you are using gedit as root. root user does not have a place for gedit preferences to be stored, and therefore the appearance can not be changed.

You would have to look into changing the way gedit looks for preferences and change that location to another by default.

Edit:

From the `man` page:

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or
> another user, as specified by the security policy.

The default when using `sudo` is that you execute the following command as the superuser (root). This user doesn't really exist in ubuntu, they don't any any home dir (/~) and they can not have any preferences like those given to regular users.

According to this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/480624/config-file-for-gedit-to-disable-line-wrap) gEdit no longer uses config files that you can edit. As it says in the link:

> You can either use dconf-editor or gsettings (CLI) to change gEdit preferences.
> In your case, to disable line-wrap either open a terminal and run:
>
> `gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor wrap-mode none`
>
> or fire-up dconf-editor and navigate to org > gnome > gedit > preferences > editor

Edit Again:

The simplest way to avoid this rabbit-hole is to use a different text editor. Try using nano:

```
sudo nano {your_file}
```

Comment: Can you expand on that for a total newbie? If I launch gedit without sudo, I can change settings it seems. At least there's no white on white in that instance, but the file is read only so it may load a different style anyway. But with sudo gedit, it looks to be an entirely different instance. I have no clue whatsoever what to do to change those settings if the GUI is unresponsive.

Comment: I've edited once more to give a really simple way to avoid this problem.

Comment: I appreciate the edits. Hoping that is what I can do when I am back home. Let's pretend I didn't like nano. How do you reference an app with a space in its name? E.g. Text Editor. I tried sudo text editor and it told me text was unrecognized app. I tried sudo "text editor" and still it didn't recognize it. I tried right clicking on the text editor app to glean some detail about how I should reference it if I want to open as an admin (vs windows just has "run as administrator") and came away with nothing for the little bit I could dig through.

Comment: No worries, if you've found this helpful please select as the answer. Unfortunately Text Editor and gEdit are one and the same. On the plus side, simply googling "text editor ubuntu" reveals an absolute forest of options, some of which are graphical (which I think might be what you're after if you want to customise themes) and some, like vim, run in the terminal. If you find a text editor you like but it only runs in the terminal, you could change your terminal preferences to whatever colours, fonts and opacity you like. Just right click the title bar.